# How to perform an exact test of Chi-square for a single-dimension data in R?

Tags: r, chi-squared

I have a data frame like this:

```
> fr.t.r
     A     B    C    D    E
Freq 13    3    0    0    0
```

and I would like to do a Chi-square test to find out if the difference among the 5 groups is significant. So I did this:

```
> chisq.test(fr.t.r)
        Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  fr.t.r
X-squared = 39.625, df = 4, p-value = 5.174e-08

Warning message:
In chisq.test(fr.t.r) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Then I thought the number of observations is small, so I need to do an exact test. But fisher.test can only be done on contingency tables. So how should I do it as what can be done in SPSS?

Comment: you could use `chisq.test(f,simulate.p.value=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks, but this is Monte Carlo test which is not suitable for my case where the sample size is so small.

Comment: Why isn't a Monte Carlo test suitable for a small sample? (e.g. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_24.0.0/spss/base/idh_exact.html says MC is most useful when the data set is too large for exact tests; it doesn't say it's inappropriate for small data sets)

Comment: I've looked around a bit at the possibilities I know of (e.g. the `coin` package is probably the best-known package for doing exact tests in R) and can only find contingency table tests. I think a MC test would probably serve the purpose, but it's not what you asked for. Can you give a link to SPSS's method? It might be possible to do this using the `partitions` package, but it seems clunky ...